# Use Conditional Formatting to format a cell based on the value of the cell before it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a range of data that I am looking to format a certain way. I would like cell B1 to turn a certain color or have an up/down arrow based on the value of A1, but I'm looking for this to repeat for the entire range of data. PLease see the image for an example of what I am looking for. In this image, the cell turns green when the cell before it is lower, and red when it is higher.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7yuR.png)

I have tried a few different methods I found online, but none have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I achieved with two simple Conditional Formatting rules.

[image]